# How to convert int timezone to string timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I want to convert this timezone 10800 to a string like "America/New York" in php. I've tried with date_default_timezone_set but it works only with strings.

Comment: Offset `10800` is not only for `America/New York` but for many other timezones. How do you expect php to choose which one do you want?

Comment: you have only one timezone? or much? because if you use just one create function convert that in string.

Comment: just only one timezone, i have an api based on people search and it gives me a timezone  for the city which people search and I ve belived that timezone will give me the timezone of the city like if he is searching Bucharest it will give you Europe/Bucharest but in int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to represent the time zone offset value as a string, the link below will help.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php

```
<?php 

$timezone_abbreviations = DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations();
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($timezone_abbreviations);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

Comment: If I am searching for Bucharest, i get a timezone which is 10800 and I belived that it is only for Europe/Bucharest. How can I do that?

Comment: "timezone":10800,"id":683506,"name":"Bucharest","cod":200

Comment: @ymy - Sorry, but this question describes a different aspect of the PHP time zone APIs, and does not attempt to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @BogdanPaul - Your belief is incorrect.  `10800` = UTC+3 - which *many* time zones use - some all year, some for only part of the year.  There are also some that have used UTC+3 in the past but no longer use it.  Time zones are complicated, and you cannot derive a time zone ID like `Europe/Bucharest` from an offset alone.